# {help}--drupal---cache_form table is too big

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cron

1,what's record cached in the table cache_form?

2,my site's cache_form table is too big(1.0G). the cron hasn't been working for a month. when i run it manually, it still can't work. why. the drupal version is 6.19.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A hot fix, would be to manually delete all the rows from the database. However, the problem is not that form table it getting to big, but that cron is failing. Not running cron on your site will cause a lot of problems, in the future if you don't find and fix that problem.

Comment: Please let me know which cron in particular, I had shutdown cron jobs on my dev server, and now size is in GB's. I will activate that particular cron through elysia or some module.

Comment: @2-Stroker Drupal only have a single cron job, which other modules hook into, it's run through the cron.php file in your drupal root.

Comment: Guess I didnt phrase it properly, sry, actually I was asking for specific `hook_cron` like `system_cron` or `search_cron` so that I can enable that particular hook alone by using Elysia module. I tried running all hooks, but still table size was around 2GB.

Comment: @2-Stroker it's `system_cron` that clears out the core cache tables.

Comment: Thanks, I have enabled that now and will check over the next week.

Answer (score 11):

```
DELETE FROM cache_form where expire < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
```

Comment: This is the BEST answer! Thanks, yuko!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with cron_cache is that is does a truncate on the tables. So that means that active sessions also gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question the cache_form holds exactly what it sounds like, cached forms. So on sites with a bunch of forms, such as a big ubercart site where every product page is an add to cart form, this table can get ginormous.

It does appear as though this table getting too big is a direct result of cron not running properly as @googletorp indicates.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Drupal7.22 and i installed the [cron_cache](http://drupal.org/project/cron_cache) module that clears all the cache including cache_form every 24hours .